# How to redirect to PAGE with GET METHOD asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm implementing an app in xamarin-forms.
For the authentication I'm using a web app asp.net (.net framework) identity framework to publish in azure. I Don't need to implement web page for app using.

I have defined the whole email confirmation part, what I am trying to do is a simple page where the user must be redirected when clicking on the email confirmation link.

This page, for the moment, will only have a text with "YOU EMAIL HAS BEEN CONFIRMED" but in the future I'll implement with other tags.

I defined this page in `Views/SuccessConfirm.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Page1</h1>
        <p class="lead">YOU EMAIL HAS BEEN CONFIRMED</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to test how this page will be shown I implemented the follow method in `Controllers/AccountController.cs` :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("check")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> check()
{
     return Ok(Redirect("./Views/SuccessConfirm");
}
```

But when I call it (`https://localhost:44335/api/Account/check`)this method return me this error. I'm not really sure that the `Redirect` method is the useful for me.

Error shown:
[image]

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET and I don't know if you need others information, please let me know.

How I can solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the controller and action for serving your `SuccessConfirm` page. 
Then you can use [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method to redirect to your action by action name and controller name, like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> check()
{
     return RedirectToAction("SuccessConfirm","SuccessConfirmController");
}
```

Comment: Ok, how I can do it?

Comment: @Enoch, please, see the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller) how you can add controller.

Comment: ok I saw It but as I said, I'm using Entity framework in .net framework, for this reason I cannot use all methods used in tutorial (for example if I add `System.Web.Mvc` It cause some conflict)